# how to set chkbox.checked to false/unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked

I do this:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByName('chkDetail')[0].checked)
```

in javascript I get:

```
true
```

And then I have done all of these (and more):

```
document.getElementsByName('chkDetail')[0].setAttribute('checked', false);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('cd').setAttribute('checked', false);
```

or

```
document.getElementsByName('chkDetail')[0].removeAttribute('checked');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('cd').removeAttribute('checked');
```

and then when I do this again:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByName('chkDetail')[0].checked)
```

I still get:

```
true
```

Nothing seems to uncheck this checkbox!

PS I have tried using "false" and 'false' which I know in coercing the boolean to a string is just evaluating as true so I also tried "" and ''.

There are a lot of sites out there that I have been to that say any of these combinations and others should work.  What could I be overlooking?

Comment: Instead of setAttribute you can use prop which will give you proper output .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
document.getElementsByName('chkDetail')[0].checked = false;
```

Check out [this reference on the `checked` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) of the element. The property can be read or written to directly.

I noticed you have a `getElementById('cd')`. If the element you want has an ID value, I would recommend using that over `getElementsByName()`. So the call would become:

```
document.getElementById('cd').checked = false;
```

Comment: OMG jwatts!  First time out!  Worked like a charm.  Accessing the property directly!  I guess I shy away from that method due to the lack of intellisense.  But really once I get past setAttribute or removeAttribute and I'm in the quoted parameter any way there isn't any more intellisense to give me any more confidence!  This is great news.  And I actually am going to move on with the app.  1. I will now remember to try the direct method more often.  But 2. I will always wonder why all the other ways that "should have worked" weren't working.

Comment: @liveFor10 If this is the first time you've worked with a scripting language, then be prepared for a LOT of trial and error. My 2 main pieces of advice for working with scripting languages: 1) make small iterative changes (ie., build up to the goal piece by piece, and 2) find a couple of really good language references. Without intellisense to help, you just have to *know* what properties and methods are available.

Comment: @liveFor10 Also, if my answer did the trick for you, please mark it as the answer so that if others find their way here, they will know what solved your coding issue. Thanks!

Comment: @liveFor10 To answer your question in your comment, I believe that `.setAttribute('checked', 'checked')` would have done the trick. `setAttribute()` and `removeAttribute()` affect the actually attributes on the element, and in HTML, the proper way to make a checkbox be checked is as such `<input type="checkbox" id="cb" checked="checked" />`.